# serving static files with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I am trying to redirect all requests to my site to my cgi script (django.cgi)
What should happen:

1. Calling `www.mysite.de/bla/anything.html` shall be redirected to the `django.cgi`
2. Calling `www.mysite.de/static/anything/my.css` shall be redirected to a static folder

`/home/page/my_site/static/anything/my.css`

So far I ve got the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^static/(.*)$ my_site/static/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ django.cgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This one gives me a 500 error. If I comment out the third line, anything works fine except for the static files are not served. How should my .htaccess look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static
RewriteRule ^ ../static/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ django.cgi [QSA,L]
```

I have moved the rule for static files up prior to the CGI rewrite. I have also used a jump to the previous folder as it is not clear as to where your `.htaccess` file is. If the rules do not work, please comment with the location of this file (it should b in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.